# Probability problem involving a moving distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have two independent continuos random variables X and Y that each vary between [x1, x2] and [y1, y2], respectively. In my problem (which is of a physical nature) I assume that X and Y are uniformly distributed. The lower/upper limits x1 & x2 vary with time and x1=k*x2 always holds, where k is a fixed constant and x2 a monotonically increasing function of time. The limits y1 and y2 are fixed and do not vary.

**Assuming x2$\ge$y1, I want to calculate the probability P(X>Y) as a function of x2.**

In terms of my own effort, I can only think of solution strategies that seem rather complicated. I cant find a simple and robust methodology. Additionally, I would like to know how a solution looks like when X and Y have arbitrary distributions.

EDIT: Using the formula for conditional probability and applying Bayes rule one gets $P(X>Y)=P(X>Y \cap Y<x_2)$. Although not sure if this helps.
Is there any way of expressing the r.h.s above using the distributions for X and Y?

Let me know if anything is missing in the problem description.

Thank you

Comment: "The lower/upper limits x1 & x2 vary with time..." -- can you elaborate on this? Do they vary in a deterministic (i.e. non-random) way? Do the $y_i$ coefficients vary as well?

Comment: Aaron: Of course! x2 will increase monotonically with time. Coefficients y1 and y2 are fixed.